# Figuring out mysql max connection limit

Tags: mysql

Having performance issues at peak times where MYSQL would go unresponsive. Trying to figure out if I am using the right value for max connections. The server has 64GB of RAM.

```
+------------------------------+------------+
| Variable_name                | Value      |
+------------------------------+------------+
| bulk_insert_buffer_size      | 8388608    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances | 1          |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size      | 134217728  |
| innodb_change_buffering      | all        |
| innodb_log_buffer_size       | 8388608    |
| join_buffer_size             | 67108864   |
| key_buffer_size              | 2147483648 |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size      | 8388608    |
| net_buffer_length            | 16384      |
| preload_buffer_size          | 32768      |
| read_buffer_size             | 67108864   |
| read_rnd_buffer_size         | 2097152    |
| sort_buffer_size             | 2097152    |
| sql_buffer_result            | OFF        |
+------------------------------+------------+

lsof | wc -l
124101

lsof -a -p MYSQLDPID | wc -l
518

mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE '%connection%';
+----------------------+----------+
| Variable_name        | Value    |
+----------------------+----------+
| Connections          | 25019772 |
| Max_used_connections | 451      |
+----------------------+----------+
```

Currently the connection limit is set to 350. Which other variables would I need to calculate correct connection limit?

Answer (score 0):

Look an the STATUS Vatiables. **Connections** and **Max_used_connections** will say you how many connections the Server has used.

```
SHOW STATUS LIKE '%connection%';

Variable_name   Value
Connection_errors_accept    0
Connection_errors_internal  0
Connection_errors_max_connections   0
Connection_errors_peer_address  0
Connection_errors_select    0
Connection_errors_tcpwrap   0
Connections 13
Max_used_connections    7
```

Comment: 25019772 and 451 respectively

Comment: Max_used_connections = Max number of connections ever open at the same time and Connections = Number of connection attempts (both successful and unsuccessful). So show how many connection are allowed in your server an set it to a good value. The values that you are posted say nothing about the response. There are many hints. Which type of Type you are using and which Querys are running at the same time. if you have Query cache enabled an can use it,.....

Comment: the best thing is to enable the slow query log and look at the EXPLAIN of the querys change them or create correct indexe and so on.